# sqlite rawquery not working correctly

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two table their names are profile and messages. I try to get profile data and last message which related by profileId from sql.

### profiles

- profileId(INTEGER)
- profileName(TEXT)
- profileImgPath(TEXT)

### messages

- messageId (INTEGER)
- profileId (INTEGER)
- messageContent (INTEGER)
- messageType (INTEGER)
- messageStatus(INTEGER)
- messageTime(TEXT)

### data examples

[image: table contents]

[image]

### my query

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();


     String selectQuery = "select " +
     "profiles.profileId," +
     "profiles.profileName," +
     "profiles.profileImgPath," +
     "profiles.profileStatus," +
     "messages.messageContent," +
     "messages.messageTime " +
     "from profiles left join messages on profiles.profileId=messages.profileId " +
     "group by profiles.profileId " +
     "order by messages.messageId DESC;";
          Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    Log.i("query",selectQuery);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            Log.i("gokberksql", c.getString(1) + "x" + c.getString(4));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
```

### results

```
gokberksql﹕ sinanxKanka naber
```

But need to return

```
gokberksql﹕ sinanxIyi senden naber
```

In addition this query working well in my computer editors but android results not correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should select the max messageTime in your query. This will give you the values of columns in the same row as the one that contains the max.

```
String selectQuery = "select " +
    "profiles.profileId," +
    "profiles.profileName," +
    "profiles.profileImgPath," +
    "profiles.profileStatus," +
    "messages.messageContent," +
    "max(messages.messageTime) as messageTime " + // <- here
    "from profiles " +
    "left join messages on profiles.profileId = messages.profileId " +
    "group by profiles.profileId" +
    "order by profiles.profileId, messages.messageId DESC;";
```

Note that this behavior was introduced in SQLite version 3.7.11, which became standard in API 16 (JellyBean). If you need to support API 15 or older, you may have to use a different query.

Comment: Thanks for helpful sharing, but i dont sort by time because next day will be have less time data and not exist date data. I think i have already sorted value which auto increment messageId column so max messageId shows last message.

Comment: That's fine, but the idea is the same: include a max() aggregate function in the query. Also, I recommend using unix timestamps since that way your message time *is* useful for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a group by profiles.profileId, that is not needed in your case since you are not doing any aggregations over the profileId group. Try with

```
String selectQuery = "select " +
   "profiles.profileId," +
   "profiles.profileName," +
   "profiles.profileImgPath," +
   "profiles.profileStatus," +
   "messages.messageContent," +
   "messages.messageTime " +
 "from profiles left join messages on   profiles.profileId=messages.profileId " +
   "order by profiles.profileId, messages.messageId DESC;";
```

Comment: Because he wants only one item per profileId, and he wants it to be the one with the latest messageTime.